# Another "can't set headers after they're sent"

Tags: node.js, express, sparql

I get a "can't set headers after they're sent" error, which I understand may be due to sending a response from my server more than once, however it doesn't seem to be the case with my code, at least on the surface. I make a query to dbpedia in order to obtain some resources, which I then send back to my client. Here's the code:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
    if (req.query.titolo){
        var response ;
        let [ artist, title ] = getArtistTitle(req.query.titolo);
        title = title.replace(" ","_");//for dbpedia resource names
        const prefixes = {
            dbo: "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/",
            db: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/"
        }
        DbPediaClient.setOptions('application/sparql-results+json',prefixes);
        DbPediaClient.query("SELECT ?abstract WHERE { db:"+title+
        " dbo:abstract ?abstract. FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en') }")
        .then((data)=>{
            response = data["results"]["bindings"][0]["abstract"]["value"] ;
            return res.json({abstract: response}) ;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

I use virtuoso-sparql-client to make a query to http://dbpedia.org/sparql (DbPediaClient is initialized outside of this function). I've already tried using res.send instead of res.json, and it still gives the same error. Which by the way it's the following:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/lorenzo/Scrivania/ProgettoTechweb/AlphaTube/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/lorenzo/Scrivania/ProgettoTechweb/AlphaTube/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at DbPediaClient.query.then (/home/lorenzo/Scrivania/ProgettoTechweb/AlphaTube/server.js:43:15)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

If you need more info please ask.

Comment: are there other routes that match `"/"` besides this one?

Comment: `if (req.query.titolo){` are there more conditions that somehow are being true at the same time like `if(...){} if(...){}`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there is another one before that. `app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
 //console.log(req.query);
 res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
 next();
});`

Comment: @Plutone11011 that's the problem. You always `res.sendFile()`. So you've already sent HTML and now you're attempting to send JSON in the same request/response cycle, which express is telling you that you can't.

Comment: @vibhor1997a I don't think so, but I'm not sure what you mean. That condition is used to check for a specific property contained in the get query. Basically I want this middleware to respond only to a specific ajax request client-side.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks. I'm still a newbie with express, so is there a way to send it just once(when launching the app at the beginning), while maintaining the same routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express is a framework that handles request/response cycles by iterating through routes that match the path specified in an HTTP request and letting your code send the response in each match or call `next()` if it didn't send one. The problem here is you have the following:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
    res.sendFile(...);
    next();
});

app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
    if (req.query.titolo){
        ...
        res.json(...);
    }
});
```

This code means

> Whenever I get an HTTP request to `/` then send some HTML, then if the request contains `titolo` in the query, send some JSON as well.

Express is telling you that you can't send anything else since you already sent the HTML.

One solution would be to move the API route above the HTML:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
    if (req.query.titolo){
        ...
        res.json(...);
    } else {
      next();
    }
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(...);
});
```

which means

> Whenever I get an HTTP request to `/`, if the request contains `titolo` in the query, send some JSON, otherwise send some HTML.

But my recommendation would be to move the API route to a different path that doesn't collide with the route for your static file, which is a lot more typical for HTTP servers.